# Can I put an iAd banner in the middle of View?

Tags: objective-c, iad

Is it possible to place iAd banner somewhere else than is top or bottom? I wish I could place it in the middle of my UIView.

tnx

Comment: I second that. In fact, I want to add iAds on tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and it will be approved if done correctly. A good example would be as a row in a UITableView, but most of the time this is a bad idea.

Comment: I have placed controlling features on the bottom and top of my app that's why I want it somewhere else. Thanx for confirmation that it will not be rejected because of that.

Comment: Where can I see the terms for ads placement.

Answer (score 1):

This would likely go against Apple's policy of iAd placement, plus your users would probably getting pretty annoyed with a banner ad popping up in the middle of the screen.

Comment: It depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it is not advised, because of Apple's HIG.